# Sought-Given-Solution-Answers

Tags: problem-solving

I am a German student attending lectures delivered in English at the KTH Stockholm. There I am supposed to solve a problem sheet, using a "Sought-Given-Solution-Answer approach".
I am not really into english math. Is it just meant to be like:
"Sought: the inverse of Matrix A" "Given: Matrix A" "Solution: blabla"?

Comment: Most likely, yes. It sounds like a rather stilted attempt to get students to identify exactly what is to be found/calculated and what information is available before diving blindly into the problem.

Comment: You left out the Answer part. In the Solution part you perform the calculations (e.g. Gauss) to calculate the inverse of $A$. But ever so often, the last tiny help for the reader, namely a summarising answer sentence "The inverse of matrix $A$ is ..." is missing. Without that, one wonders if the student gave up calculations in the middle, did not know what to do next or did not see the answer-forest because of the many calculation-trees.

Comment: Perhaps it's a translation from something with a cute acronym in Swedish. Do you have native fellow students you can ask?